# How to change background color of selected or clicked cell in a pyqt5 QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am new to pyqt. I am trying to change the background color of selected cell in a QTableWidget. Is it possible to change color when clicked/selected and return to default color when not selected.

Also the property `cellClicked` is returning only row number. How to get both row and column number?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1124, 801)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 1000, 600))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(15)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        for i, col_name in enumerate(['symbol', 'step', 'factor', 'initial_lot', 'max_streak', 'status']):
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, QTableWidgetItem(col_name))
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(
            "QHeaderView::section{"
            "border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4848;"
            "background-color:white;"
        "}")

        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(lambda x: self.print_selected(x))
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

    def print_selected(self, s):
        print(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

python 3.7.6, pyqt5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use QPalette.Highlight

```
pallete = self.tableWidget.palette()
hightlight_brush = pallete.brush(QPalette.Highlight)
hightlight_brush.setColor(QColor('red'))
pallete.setBrush(QPalette.Highlight, hightlight_brush)
self.tableWidget.setPalette(pallete)
```

cellClicked signal passes both row, and column:

> void QTableWidget::cellClicked(int row, int column)

Comment: The highlight part is working fine. But cellClicked doesn't return both row and column, when the 'print_selected' functioned is triggered after cellClick. You can observe that if you run the code above.

Comment: self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(lambda row, col: print(row, col))